# Display only certain rows in datatable

Tags: vb.net

So I have a dataset like below

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Apple   1       10  Orange
Apple   2       20  Orange
Apple   3       30  Orange
Apple   1       10  Pear
Apple   2       20  Pear
Apple   3       30  Pear
Orange  1       10  grapes
Orange  2       20  grapes
ORange  1       10  kiwi
Berries 1       10  apple
Berries 1       20  Kiwi
```

I just need something like

```
   Col1 Col2    Col3    Col4
   Apple    1     10    Orange
   Apple    2     20    Orange
   Apple    3     30    Orange
   ORange   1     10    Grapes
   Orange   2     20    Grapes
   Berries  1     10    Apple
```

So basically it is the col1 and col4, if col4 changes for col1 as I read through the rows, I should'nt display that

Could someone please help me

After first's suggestion

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To dtResults.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim firstItem As String = dtResults.Rows(i)("col1").ToString()
        Dim firstToB As String = dtResults.Rows(i)("col4").ToString()
        dtResults.DefaultView.RowFilter = "col4= '" + firstToB + "'"
        Dim tempTable As DataTable = dtResults.DefaultView.ToTable()
        Dim Total As Integer = 0
        For Each dr As DataRow In tempTable.Rows
            'Dim firstItem As String = dr("col1").ToString()


            'If (dr("col1") = firstItem) AndAlso (firstToBin = dr("col4")) Then

            If item Is Nothing OrElse item <> dr("col1") Then
                If Not item Is Nothing Then
                    dgv.Rows.Add()
                End If
                itemnum = dr("col1")

            Else
                itemnum = ""
                desc = ""
                size = ""
                Total += dr("col3")
            End If
            item = dr("col1")
            dgv.Rows.Add(dr('',dr('',dr('')...)
            count += 1
            'End If
        Next

    Next
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to fix it at the source. Where does the data come from?

Comment: It comes from parameters passed to a stored procedure

Comment: What is causing you to filter? A user that types in text into a textbox? Please try to explain the scenario that a user would go through in order to achieve your result...

Comment: Then your best option to update the stored procedure to give the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to achieve as mentioned in the question here is what I did. I can always make changes in Stored procedure but I should be able to see those rows also in dataset for some other purpose. And so to bind the Grid I took row's item like below loop through

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dtResults.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim firstItem As String = dtResults.Rows(i)("col1").ToString()

        If acceptitem Is Nothing OrElse acceptitem <> firstItem Then
            Dim firstToB As String = dtResults.Rows(i)("col4").ToString()
            dtResults.DefaultView.RowFilter = "col4 = '" + firstToB + "' AND col1 = '" + firstItem + "'"
            Dim tempTable As DataTable = dtResults.DefaultView.ToTable()

            Dim Total As Integer = 0 ' dtResults.Rows(i)("col3").ToString()
            For Each dr As DataRow In tempTable.Rows


                acceptitem = dr("col1").ToString()
                If item Is Nothing OrElse item <> dr("col1") Then
                    If Not item Is Nothing Then
                        dgv.Rows.Add()
                    End If
                    itemnum = dr("col1")
                    Total += Convert.ToInt16(dr("col3").ToString())

                Else
                    itemnum = ""
                                         Total += Convert.ToInt16(dr("col3").ToString())
                End If
                item = dr("col1")
                dgv.Rows.Add(dr('',dr('',dr('').......)

                count += 1

            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks so much for all the other suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to filter through your DataTable's rows. You can use the DefaultView in order to do this.

For example:

```
Dim ds1 As New DataSet1 'Create an instance of your DataSet1
ds1.yourDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Col4='Orange'"
```

If your DataSet's DataTables are created in the Visual Studio's designer, you can specify the DataType (string, integer, boolean) for each column. By default the DataType is set to a string.
[image]

You can do this in two ways

- [Filtering and Sorting using DataViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69c06922(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [Filtering and Sorting using DataTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Could you please see what I have done with your suggestion. It didn't quite help me

Comment: @nysu I might not be comprehending what you're trying to do but to me, these two lines of code would replace your loop...

dtResults.DefaultView.RowFilter = "col4='Orange'"   .... ...

dgv.DataSource = dtResults.DefaultView

Comment: I see what you are saying. But I got this done as I wanted. Will post the answer soon.